# Use Java API in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is it possible to use a Java API in Kotlin. For example I want to use a Barcode Scanner API, which ist written in Java, in my Kotlin code. So how can I use the constructor? In Java it is `new BarcodeScanner()` how can I do this in Kotlin

Comment: Of course you can. Or simply, instead of `new` keyword which mentioned by another user, write your codes in `Java` class language (if you're beginner in `Kotlin`) then use `Code -> Convert java file to Kotlin file` and it will convert it to Kotlin which is a good place to start Kotlin and learning how it can be changed from java to kotlin.

Comment: [This](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/mixing-java-kotlin-intellij.html) might be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same just without the `new` keyword.

```
val scanner = BarcodeScanner()
```